# How you can see exactly what a memory leaked?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, memory

for example, for Windows logical to use the Task Manager. But some people say that this utility does not show the exact value of the memory allocated by user. Then where can I see it?

I do not trust all classes, which calculates New\Delete. Smart pointers also is not are guaranteed result. I want to see the situation on the exit.

Thanks.

Comment: There are tools like valgrind which would help you analyze all memory allocation and free operations within your program at runtime.

Comment: Windows (or at least the Microsoft compiler/library) include [leak tracing capabilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/x98tx3cf.aspx).

Comment: I search simple program like Task Manager, which can show me value of allocated memory.

Comment: Look at this thread for possible windows alternatives to valgrind: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows

Answer (score 1):

I assume you expect answer for Windows platform.

[Rational Purify](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/purify/) and [Insure++](http://www.parasoft.com/jsp/products/insure.jsp;jsessionid=aaahzrRD2vGtyL?itemId=63) are capable of this.

EDIT: Just saw [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477).